# How to write this formula in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I have this formula to solve.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y1ZJC.png)

And here is my code that outputs an error in the formula.

```
Private Sub CommandButton6_Click()
Dim Z As String
Dim X As Double, Y As Double
Z = InputBox("Input number X!", "Inputing number X"): X = Val(Z)
Y = Sqr(2 * ((X - 2) ^ 2) * ((8 - X) - 1)^1/3
MsgBox ("Y =" + Str(Y))
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the error it throws?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking into account when we get negative result under the root

```
Y = (2 * ((X - 2) ^ 2) * (8 - X) - 1)
If Y >= 0 Then
    Y = Y ^ (1 / 3)
Else
    Y = -(Abs(Y) ^ (1 / 3))
End If
```

This is the answer for your 2nd question in comments

```
Y = (2 * (X ^ 2) * (X - 6))
If Y >= 0 Then
    Y = 1 + (Y ^ (1 / 3))
Else
    Y = 1 - (Abs(Y) ^ (1 / 3))
End If
```

You can add round if you want, but haven't seen any rounding used in the image link.

Comment: This is not equivalent to the expression in the OP's question.

Comment: How so? Explain please

Comment: Thanks a lot. What about this one? It prints the same error but idk what's wrong. Y = Round(1 + ((2 * X) ^ 2) * (X - 6)) ^ (1 / 3)

The task: https://imgurhd.ru/8qcj

Comment: @milo5m There's a Sqr() function call missing from your answer that's in the OP's question.  Also, I've seen several different iterations of your answer appear, it looked like you were editing it online until you found something that might work.  Personally, I find it less confusing for everyone involved if I figure out what my answer is going to be, then post the completed response in one go.

Comment: @FKEinternet First of all, he made a mistake with sqr, check the image he posted as a reference. You see how roles reversed quickly.

Comment: Yes, I made the same mistake - I only looked at his code, not the image.  Now that I *have* looked at the image, my interpretation of it is  Y = 1 + (((2 * x^2) * (x-6)) ^ (1/3))  which can be reduced to Y = 1 + (2 * x^2 * (x-6)) ^ (1/3) given operator precedence, as you have in your final answer.  I hadn't taken into account the negative value factor, and I recognize your answer as correct :)

Comment: To be fair, my 1st answer was semi-correct or incomplete (no negative val considered at all), that is why I had to edit it fast :) Cheers man